# printing tibble to console with a message

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

How can I print a tibble to the console along with a message? 
I want to write a function which outputs a tibble along with a verbose message that contains some information about the nature of that tibble.

Here is a highly simplistic example of what I have in mind. In the first attempt, the function doesn't work. In the second attempt, it works but outputs some other unnecessary details.

```r
# libraries needed
library(crayon)
library(tibble)

# writing the function
try.fn1 <- function() {
  # prepare the tibble
  x <- tibble::as.tibble(x = rnorm(1:10))
  # output the associated message to the user of the function
  base::message(
    cat(crayon::blue("The tibble I prepared is-"), x)
    )
  base::message(print(x))
}

# using the function
try.fn1()
#> The tibble I prepared is-
#> Error in cat(crayon::blue("The tibble I prepared is-"), x): argument 2 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'

# another attempt
try.fn2 <- function() {
  # prepare the tibble
  x <- tibble::as.tibble(x = rnorm(1:10))
  # output the associated message to the user of the function
  base::message(
    cat(crayon::blue("The tibble I prepared is-"))
  )
  base::message(print(x))
}

# using the function
try.fn2()
#> The tibble I prepared is-
#> 
#> # A tibble: 10 x 1
#>       value
#>       <dbl>
#>  1 -0.00529
#>  2  0.562  
#>  3 -0.511  
#>  4 -0.260  
#>  5 -0.232  
#>  6 -1.92   
#>  7 -0.698  
#>  8  2.38   
#>  9  1.59   
#> 10 -0.585
#> c(-0.00528727617885923, 0.56168758575177, -0.510982641120654, -0.260458372988822, -0.231847890601322, -1.91514178853023, -0.697661618989503, 2.37722341810185, 1.5869372625472, -0.584576993642516)
```

Created on 2018-03-15 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: If you're looking at printing (in `tibble`-fashion) a `tbl`, would it help to see `tibble:::print.tbl_df`?

Comment: @r2evans There is neither `dplyr::print.tbl_df` nor `tibble::print.tbl_df` anymore. I think those functions have been deprecated in recent versions of these packages.

Comment: [Wrong](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/blob/35dfee5bb2bd0594588d20a2baf9220059247dcd/R/tbl-df.r#L23-L32). I used three colons, you only used two. So they are not exported, that was never an assertion. And whether you use the functions or not, perhaps their *code* could help you in your quest.

Comment: Hah, that worked! I just used google and `??` to look for it. I had no idea that there is this whole `:::` thing and thought that that was a typo. Mind posting this answer so that I can accept it and close this thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you either *use* or *mimic* the code within the unexported `print` functions from `tibble`. To access unexported functions, use triple-colons to access `tibble:::print.tbl_df` (and `.tbl`).

Two things to know to know to look for these functions:

1. Many functions in R have different behaviors (even different arguments) based on the object(s) called in them. For instance, `summary` behaves differently if given an `lm` object, a `matrix, etc. To see all of the different`summary`functions, try`methods(summary)`. (A good reference for learning more about this, called "S3", can be seen in Hadley's [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html) online book.)

   If you bring this around to this question, running `methods("print")` presents (among others):

   ```
   m <- methods("print")
   m[ grepl("tbl|frame",m) ]
   # [1] "print.data.frame" "print.frame"      "print.tbl_cube"   "print.tbl_df"    
   # [5] "print.tbl_lazy"   "print.tbl_sql"
   ```

   These don't have to be *exported* by their respective packages to be made available to R. In fact, I seem to find more of them unexported. The fact that `print(my_new_object)` just simply *works* can be a huge convenience to users new and experienced.
2. You can always find the source for this function online (such as on GitHub, like this source [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/blob/35dfee5bb2bd0594588d20a2baf9220059247dcd/R/tbl-df.r#L23-L32)), but this is not always convenient, and if you aren't careful, it could be for a version of the package other than what you have installed.

   Most objects in R can be inspected (deeply or otherwise) just by typing the name on the console. This works just as well for variables as it does for functions. There are three ways to look at functions:

   1. After `library(pkgname)` or `require(pkgname)`, just type the function name. This is how most people learn and interact with R.
   2. Even before loading a package with `library` or `require`, you can view any package's functions with [double-colons](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ns-dblcolon.html), for example `dplyr::filter`. This is also useful when a function name is shared between packages (possible "masking" or collisions), and you want to be clear which one to use.
   3. If a function is not exported, no matter if you've called `library` or not, you can only access it with the triple-colons, such as `tibble:::print.tbl_df`. (Actually, there are ways to view the source without the colons such as in R's `browser`, but that's not important here.)

There is a risk with using unexported functions. They are typically unexported for one of several reasons, including most importantly (a) not central to the function of the package, and (b) the author has no need or intention of maintaining that function's API (arguments, output) between releases. It is possible (and happens frequently) that an unexported function may disappear, change arguments dramatically, or change methods. Essentially an author has invested in maintaining some semblance of connsistency on exported functions, but not the unexported ones.

So by suggesting you look at or use `tibble:::print.tbl_df`, there's risk: it is possible that they will change or remove that function. Having said that, the `print.*` functions are often unexported because they are intended to only be used using the generic S3 version, `print`. The only reason I would expect this specific function to change is if the authors changed the spelling or type of objects the package uses. And I don't see that happening any time soon.

Answer (score 1):

Capture standard output, which is where `cat()` and `print()` send output, then concatenate and pass to message:

```
message(paste(capture.output({
  cat(crayon::blue("The tibble I prepared is-\n"))
  print(x)
}), collapse = "\n"))
```